# How can I enable the internet on other apps other than the web browser?

Tags: applications, wi-fi, internet

The wifi that I am using requires me to input a username and password for it to work. I can successfully do this on the web browser (chrome) as it brings up a webpage (ie 192.168.1.1/login). However, I can't access any other apps as I believe that I haven't inputted my username and password into those corresponding apps(and I don't think I'm actually able to either (like with gmail or spotify)).

So I was thinking that a solution to this would be to find an app that would allow me to globally access internet to all apps. Any suggestions?

Comment: It doesn't make any difference which app you use. Logging into the Wi-Fi from Chrome makes it work for your whole phone, not just for Chrome. What symptoms are you actually seeing?

Comment: This indeed sounds like a "captive portal". For details, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal). As Dan wrote: once logged in, your *device* is authorized – not just the browser. That "portal soft" stores your "access permission" based on your device's [MAC address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) – though maybe for a limited time (usually a few ours up to a few days).

Answer (score 1):

You normally can login in your browser i.e: http://1.1.1.1 (or any local address)  and put your credentials, user and password.

If are valid, your mobile its accepted to use the network for all apps, until you disconnect.

Otherwise you can set a proxy for some apps, as social apps or browsers.